# Quickfixj Initiator to reconnect to session after internet disconnection

Tags: quickfixj

is there a way to reconnect to the session and keep the program alive after a disconnect from the internet? It seems like once the internet goes out, the entire quickfixj program will just stop.

By disconnecting the router:
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

or

By turning on a vpn to start sending from an unauthorized ip:
java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the socket initiator is still alive but the program still shuts down. CountDownLatch will prevent it from happening